# How to deploy Jenkins extension point

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write an extension point to the [dependency graph view plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dependency+Graph+View+Plugin).

I read the documentation on extension points but didn't find how to deploy my implementation. 
I guess I need to reference somehow the original plugin to get the method to implement (how can I get it - is it in a jar? is it the jpl?)

And than I write my own code.
Now what?
do I create my own jar? where should I put it?
do I need to change anything in Jenkins config?

Comment: You deploy your implementation as a Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable but I couldn't  find it anywhere in the documentation. If you write this as an answer I would gladly accept it

Comment: The one answer below is pretty good in general, so I edited it to add my comment at the start. So you can accept that answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some code that extends a Jenkins extension point, this code should be packaged and deployed as a Jenkins plugin.

---

Typically you start with the [Hello World Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) and read [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Before+starting+a+new+plugin) before duplicating any effort

> One of Jenkins' main strengths is its plugins (and their openness).
>   Over a thousand are already available, and brand new plugins become
>   available every week or so. As such, there's quite likely one or more
>   plugins which cover your needs.
>
> In case some existing plugins partly cover your needs, we encourage
>   you to contribute directly to these plugins rather than starting new
>   ones from scratch. Profusion of plugins is good, profusion of plugins
>   doing the same thing or so is not as good

And once you have something you want to share you ask on the [Jenkins Developer Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jenkinsci-dev) for it to be forked to the jenkins github repo - you should probably develop somewhere else on github to start with.

If you want to include other jenkins plugins into your plugin then you can include them in the POM

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>script-security</artifactId>
         <version>1.13</version>
  </dependency>
```

As shown in the [POM for the Matrix Project Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/matrix-project-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml)

The jenkins github repo is a good place to look for examples

Comment: Thanks,  as far as I understand what you write is relevant if I want to write a new plugin - which I don't. I simply wish to implement an extension point to an existing plugin